# SP2013 Foundation: Can't find fba users on central admin (site collection administrator, people picker)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, forms-authentication, people-picker

I've configured the FBA authentication on IIS in the following manner:

1. Created the aspnetdb
2. Configured the providers in each web.config (application, central admin and Security Token Service Applicaion [STS]).
3. On the central admin, configured the Claims authentication of the web application to use the providers in the STS.
4. Configured the people picker wildcard on the provider in the application.

Still, when I go to define a site collection administrator on central admin, it can't find any users.

Notes:
Web application is configured to only use FBA.

Edit #1: the providers were configured with different names on each web application (e.g., FBA_Sharepoint _Membership, FBA_CentralAdmin_Membership.... etc)

The problem persists.

Edit #2:
I've gave permissions to the aspnet db in MSSQL to all accounts related to sharepoint and the problem persists. 
All the accounts associated with the application pools (identity) have permission to the database.

The problem persists.

**More details:**

STS RoleManager:

`<roleManager defaultProvider="FBA_STS_RoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="FBA_STS_RoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="FBA_STS_ConnectionString" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>`

STS Membership:

`<membership defaultProvider="FBA_STS_MembershipProvider">
       <providers>
                <add name="FBA_STS_MembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="FBA_STS_ConnectionString" enablePasswordReset="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" passwordFormat="Clear" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" />
 </providers>
 </membership>`

Central Admin Membership:

`<membership defaultProvider="FBA_CentralAdmin_MembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="FBA_CentralAdmin_MembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="FBA_CentralAdmin_ConnectionString" enablePasswordReset="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" passwordFormat="Clear" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" />
            </providers>
        </membership>`

Central Admin Role Manager:

`<roleManager defaultProvider="FBA_CentralAdmin_RoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="FBA_CentralAdmin_RoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="FBA_CentralAdmin_ConnectionString" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>`

Comment: How you created the users in the database? Is the users migrated from someother place or are those newly created users?

Comment: Does the farm account has permission to the aspnet database?

Comment: Check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31377/fba-and-the-people-picker

Comment: @AmalHashim, thanks. I've created the users, through the IIS manager, after configuring the providers.
The farm account does have db_owner permissions on the aspnet database.

Comment: @AmalHashim, also, the providers were configurated with different names on each web application (e.g., FBA_Sharepoint _Membership, FBA_CentralAdmin_Membership.... etc).
I'll edit the question so it mentions this.

Comment: @JussiPalo, thanks. I think it's a slightly different problem. Nevertheless, I've gave permissions to the aspnet db in MSSQL to all accounts related to sharepoint and the problem persists. 
All the accounts associated with the application pools (identity) have permission to the database.

Comment: can you provide us the <roleManager> and <membership> from the STS and CA.

You can try to follow this post [link](https://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/configuring-forms-base-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010-using-iis7/) I use it even in sps 2013

Comment: @Marco. I've provided the details you asked on the question. Thanks. I will checkout the link and give feedback.

Comment: @Marco, that link is actually for 2010. But thanks, anyway.

Comment: yes @JoãoTiagoSantos but it works on 2013 as 2010 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created new providers for each web application (central admin, application and security token service), but with the same name. Configured the people picker to use that name and now the people picker works.

I got another issue, but I'll post a new question.